# Comparing two counts

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two counts one is data frame and another one is output file. I need to compare both and print error if counts are different

Data frame count:

`val dfcount = df.count.toInt`

Input count :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader

var count = 0

val inputStream:FSDataInput = StreamfileSystem.open(dataFile)

val reader: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))

var line: String = reader.readLine()

while(line!=null){
    count+=1
    line = reader.readLine()
}
```

I need to compare both counts and if they are equal - do nothing, if not equal - print error

Comment: `if (dfcount != count) println("Not equal")` should work. Otherwise, please show what have you tried and what didn't work

Comment: Can we do it try catch block . If count not matches then need to exit from the code. No further execution

Answer (score 0):

```
object Main extends Logging {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  
try{
  val dfcount = df.count.toLong

    import java.io.BufferedReader
    import java.io.InputStreamReader

    var count:Long = 0

    val inputStream:FSDataInput = StreamfileSystem.open(dataFile)

    val reader: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))

    var line: String = reader.readLine()

    while(line!=null){
        count+=1
        line = reader.readLine()
    }


    if (dfcount == count) 
    { logInfo("Counts are equal")
    } else return
} catch {
case e: Exception => logError("Main Error: " + e)
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can we do it try catch block . If count not matches then need to exit from the code. No further execution

Comment: yes we can do , for that you need to  keep all codes in one Method (def ) and have to return in case mismatch. Wait I am updating code.